# Using Google Places Web Service in an Android app

Tags: android, google-places-api

All of the Android APIs for Google Place searches return predictions, and these are not as accurate or as complete as the Place Search web service.  Though predictions usually deliver the desired place, I've bumped into scenarios where they don't.  I want to use the Android API as a primary search tool, but offer the user a search button that delivers more complete results (like those returned by the web service).

I've validated that I have a working web api-key with this url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=47.725977,-122.047113&keyword=home%20depot&rankBy=distance&key=my-key

In a test app, I called this exact url using HttpURLConnection, and I also use an app-specific API key to validate that I can use GoogleApiClient to to get location information (lattitude and longitude).  Here's a screen shot of the result:

[image]

I've been unable to successfully call a Google Place web service from my app, regardless of keys I provide (including an Unrestricted key).  Google doesn't seem to want us to use web services from an app, though there are a couple of StackOverflow questions that imply it's possible.

My questions are (1) is it technically feasible to call Google Places WS from an app, and (2) if not, is there an alternative in the Android API that I'm overlooking that would achieve the detailed search results I need?

Comment: 1) I believe you are correct in assuming that Google wants to separate browser calls from in app. Also you do know about the default usage limits for these APIs: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage 2) Considering that detailed place information is a competitive advantage - look for other sources/apps which may have those APIs.

Comment: I'm paying attention to licensing issues.  I don't really need detailed place info, just a reliable way to get Google's PlaceId and coordinates.  When I search for "starbucks", there are three locations within 2 miles of my house that aren't listed in predictions.  When I call the webservice with the same string, it returns the google PlaceId and its coordinates for all three of the nearest starbucks locations.  I just want that search capability as a backup to the normal prediction capability.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? Im not able to find anything credible